# Unable to open Excel file using Pyexcel

Tags: python-3.x, pyexcel

I want to open a simple excel file using PyExcel and here is my code

```
>>import  os
>>import pyexcel as pe

>>print('Directory Path=', os.getcwd())
   Directory Path= C:\Users\Contacts\My experimentation
>>sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name="C:/Users/Contacts/My experimentation/Mylist.xlsx")
```

[image]

This is the name of my Excel file.
And this is the error I am getting

```
Directory Path= C:\Users\Contacts\My experimentation

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Contacts/My experimentation/abc.py", line 5, in <module>
    sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name="C:/Users/Contacts/My experimentation/Mylist.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\core.py", line 36, in get_sheet
    named_content = sources.get_sheet_stream(**keywords)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py", line 20, in get_sheet_stream
    sheets = a_source.get_data()
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Is this the full error statement you're getting? try upgrading setuptools

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: raise exceptions.SupportingPluginAvailableButNotInstalled(message)
pyexcel_io.exceptions.SupportingPluginAvailableButNotInstalled: Please install one of these plugins for read data in 'xlsx': pyexcel-xls,pyexcel-xlsx

Comment: pip install --upgrade setuptools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution might be installing this plugin to support the XLS file format:

```
pip install pyexcel-xls
```

for XLSX, then `pip install pyexcel-xlsx`. Just go to your scripts folder and open command window there and write down the command. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm glad I was of any help.

Comment: Can you please take a look at one more problem I am facing>>>>>>>>>>> Appending dataframe in XLSX using pyexcel- python

Thanks!

Comment: Ya sure I can help but whats the problem?

Comment: Can you please search the following in search bar of stackoverflow>>>>>>>>>>>> Appending dataframe in XLSX using pyexcel- python Thanks!

Comment: I made a comment there. Check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148958/discussion-between-biswa-9937-and-programmer).